# DeepClone / Serializing a List<item> with protobuf-net V3

Tags: protobuf-net

We try to upgrade protobuf-net from V2 to V3 and run into an issue we hope you can point us into the right direction.
We have a class that contains a List of elements:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public List<ListItem> List { get; set; } = new List<ListItem>();
}
```

When trying to create a DeepClone or to serialize we get the message:

> System.NotSupportedException : Nested or jagged lists, arrays and maps are not supported:
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[customizations.Test.IgnoreListHandlingTest+ListItem]

This worked in V2 but in V3 not. Is there any way to serialize this type of classes and get back the V2 behavior?

Many thanks for your hints.

An example that shows which type of serialization failes in V3 while working in V2 can be found here: [Example](https://www.ilogixx.de/protobuf-net.zip)

Answer (score 0):

This *should* just work; indeed, the following works fine:

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new ClassToSerialize { List = { new ListItem { Id = 42 } } };
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
        System.Console.WriteLine(clone.List.Single().Id); // 42
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public List<ListItem> List { get; set; } = new List<ListItem>();
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ListItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So I can only conclude that there is something unusual about your `ListItem` type (the `ListItem` type is not shown in the question). Most likely, it looks "list-like", although I would have *expected* that to cause v2 to complain with exactly the same error message. If v2 is somehow overlooking the listishness of a type, you might be able to further convince v3 with:

```cs
[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]
public class ListItem // not shown - some list-like-APIs here
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

---

If that doesn't help, I strongly recommend updating the question to show a minimal repro, i.e. something *runnable* (like the above is) that demonstrates what you are seeing.